# Does Lodash have an inverse to _.keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, javascript-objects, lodash

Does LoDash have a method that will do the opposite of `_.keys`, taking an array and assigning values to keys and an arbitrary string to every value?  Like this:

```
var list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

var object = _.✨unicornize✨ (list, '-')

console.log (object)  // expect {'a': '-', 'b': '-', 'c': '-'}
```

Does LoDash have a built-in to do this?  If not, what's an elegant way to this?

Comment: Not exactly a single function: `_.object(list.map(k => [k, '-']))`. And in ES2015: `list.reduce((acc, k) => ({...acc, [k]: '-'}), {});`

Comment: @zerkms wow, that's pretty short.  Sadly ES6/BabelJS aren't an option and  the time complexity on that would be pretty bad.

Comment: @SuperScript: "*the time complexity on that can't be great*" - huh, why that?

Comment: @SuperScript: `_.object(_.map(list, function(k){ return [, '-'];}))`

Comment: @zerkms: Object spreading is not ES2015. Rather use `Object.assign`.

Comment: @Bergi yep, I know :-) Just hoped no one will notice that :-D

Answer (score 2):

This seems a lot like a [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) challenge :)

Solution #1:

```
_.mapValues(_.invert(list), _.constant('-'))
```

Solution #2:

```
_.zipObject(list, _.fill(new Array(list.length), '-'))
```

Solution #3:

```
_.zipObject(_.map(list, function (v, k) { return [v, '-'] }))
// or, if you would use arrow functions:
_.zipObject(_.map(list, (v, k) => [v, '-']))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
_.mapValues(_.keyBy(list), _.constant('-'))
```